# Build issues - - “ReferencePath” does not define a value for metadata “CopyLocal”

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, auth0

After adding Auth0 package (Auth0.OidcClient.WinForms) to my VSTO Outlook plugin I started to migrate the packages.config to PackageReference using the tool provided by Visual Studio.

Still at compile time I face this problem :

> The item
> "C:<User>.nuget\packages\system.runtime.windowsruntime\4.6.0\buildTransitive\net461....\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll"
> in item list "ReferencePath" does not define a value for metadata
> "CopyLocal". In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by
> specifying %(ReferencePath.CopyLocal), or ensure that all items in
> this list define a value for this metadata.

I tried to modify also the .targets file present in : `C:\Users\<User>\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.windowsruntime\4.6.0\buildTransitive\net461` in vain.

Any hint on how to get rid of this error?

P.S: I've read all other posts related to this error in Stackoverflow, no previous answers worked.